# Firebase Admin SDK - Manually change a user's password through firebase functions with Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Is there a way to manually change a user's password through firebase functions with Admin SDK?
I tried to do this using `updateUser` method in the Admin SDK but I'm not sure if it's the right approach.

What I'm trying to do is to have an action button which defaults the password to "Password@123" on the dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the `updateUser()` method, as shown in the [Admin SDK doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).

If you want to call the Cloud Function (which uses this method) from your app you can use a Callable Cloud Function.